# Gridview disappears inside an update panel

Tags: gridview, updatepanel

I have a gridview inside an update panel and a treeview on the left side. When i click on a node, data is populated in grid view.

The gridview disappears when page index change event is fired. 
Im binding the data on page index change.
This does not happen when i remove the update panel :(

Please help me!
Thanks

.aspx.cs

protected void grdTestScripts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdTestScripts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdTestScripts.PageSize = contextObj.Pages;

```
    if (Session["RowFilter"].ToString() == "0")
    {
        DataSet dsTC = new DataSet();
        UIClassObject obj = new UIClassObject();
        StringBuilder strBuild = new StringBuilder();
        TreeView tvTestCases = ((TreeView)this.Master.FindControl("pnlTreeView").FindControl("tvTestCases"));
        strBuild.Append(tvTestCases.SelectedNode.Value + ",");
        GetSuiteIDS(tvTestCases.SelectedNode.ChildNodes, strBuild);

        obj.SuiteIDS = strBuild.ToString().TrimEnd(',').TrimStart(',');
        dsTC = BALSuite.GetSuiteSpecificTestScripts(obj);

        grdTestScripts.DataSource = dsTC.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        grdTestScripts.DataBind();
        DisplayTestSummary(dsTC);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I found out the error. Inside the update panel, it was throwing an exception due to invalid HTML being generated. Since i had disabled the javascript debugging, the records were not bound to the gridview.